# Python Pandas - How to format and split a text in column ?

Tags: python, pandas, text-mining, data-analysis

I have a set of strings in a dataframe like below

```
ID TextColumn
1 This is line number one
2 I love pandas, they are so puffy
3 [This $tring is with specia| characters, yes it is!]
```

A. I want to format this string to eliminate all the special characters
B. Once formatted,  I'd like to get a list of unique words (space being the only split)

Here is the code I have written:

get_df_by_id dataframe has one selected frame, say ID 3.

```
#replace all special characters
formatted_title = get_df_by_id['title'].str.replace(r'[\-\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\[\]\;\'\.\,\/\{\}\:\"\<\>\?]' , '')
# then split the words
results = set()
get_df_by_id['title'].str.lower().str.split().apply(results.update)
print results
```

But when I check output, I could see that special characters are still in the list.

```
Output

set([u'[this', u'is', u'it', u'specia|', u'$tring', u'is!]', u'characters,', u'yes', u'with'])
```

Intended output should be like below:

```
set([u'this', u'is', u'it', u'specia', u'tring', u'is', u'characters,', u'yes', u'with'])
```

Why does formatted dataframe still retain the special characters?

Comment: `u'is'` is repeated in the intended output. Do you need the unique words from all the strings in the column or do you want it row-wise?

Comment: 3rd and 9th word in original DF is 'is'. May be set is not eliminating duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can first [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) special characters (I add `\|` to the end), then [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) text, [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `\s+` (arbitrary wtitespaces). Output is DataFrame. So you can [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it to `Series`, [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and last [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print (df['title'].str
                  .replace(r'[\-\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\[\]\;\'\.\,\/\{\}\:\"\<\>\?\|]','')
                  .str
                  .lower()
                  .str
                  .split('\s+', expand=True)
                  .stack()
                  .drop_duplicates()
                  .tolist())

['this', 'is', 'line', 'number', 'one', 'i', 'love', 'pandas', 'they', 'are', 
'so', 'puffy', 'tring', 'with', 'specia', 'characters', 'yes', 'it']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the list of unique words per row:

```
>>> get_df_by_id['title'].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', '').str.lower().str.split('\s+').apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))

0                           [this, is, one, line, number]
1                 [love, i, puffy, so, are, they, pandas]
2    [specia, this, is, it, characters, tring, yes, with]
Name: title, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign formatted values to same data frame

```
get_df_by_id['title'] = get_df_by_id['title'].str.replace(r'[\-\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\[\]\;\'\.\,\/\{\}\:\"\<\>\?]' , '')
```

Comment: Thanks virus, I had tried it and it gave below error:

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: seems its just warning . i guess you got expected output

Comment: can you try add settings like
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None